# Multithreaded testing in a Kotlin Android Projects, Alternative to sleep()

Tags: android, kotlin, integration-testing

I have the following test code;

```
class MainActivityTest {
@get:Rule
var mActivityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

@Test
fun changeActivityOrientationToLandscape() {
    mActivityTestRule.activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    val view = mActivityTestRule.activity.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.fragment_layout)
    assertNotNull(view)
}

@Test
fun changeActivityOrientationToPortrait() {
    mActivityTestRule.activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    val view = mActivityTestRule.activity.findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)
    assertNotNull(view)
}
}
```

This works fine, but I think there is probably a better way to handle it. I would like the first line of both tests to finish executing before getting a view object, currently I do that by making the thread to sleep `Thread.sleep(5000)`.

This method assumes that the the orientation changed within 5 seconds, which isn't necessarily the case, and it is very slow.

I have tried searching for the answer but everything seems to use different additional frameworks or require additional program code, this seems like something that should be simple and frequently done within kotlin and I'm suprised I haven't been able to find anything simpler to help.

Comment: Why do you want to sleep in the first place?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu because requesting an orientation change takes place on the UI thread and is therefore an asynchronous task. calling `findViewById` executes on the main thread. I need to wait for the orientation to change to get the a specific view only available in each orientation.

Comment: Did you checked https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/OrientationEventListener?